# How to pass a List of Bitmaps effectively from an Activity to an other?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a List of 3 `Mat` `Opencv` objects, I need to pass this list from an activity to an other in `Android`.

I have no clue how to share this List of Mats between activities, so I converted those `Mat` objects to Bitmaps and now I have to deal with Bitmaps.

I know that `Bitmap` class  implements `Parcelable` by default so I used `putParcelableArrayList` like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(InputProcessingActivity.this, CompareActivity.class);
intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("", mats);
startActivity(intent);
```

But my `Application` just become dark and stays that way, I think this is happening because Bitmap objects are too large.

Can you suggest a solution to make this happen ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's something you intend to persist only at runtime I'd suggest you to store that list in a singleton object and then read from it on your next activity.

It's a pretty easy, straightforward and CPU/IO-friendly way to solve your problem.

Example:

```
public class BitmapDTO {

    private static BitmapDTO instance;

    public static BitmapDTO getInstance() {
        if (instance == null)
            instance = new BitmapDTO();
        return instance;
    }

    private List<Bitmap> bitmaps;

    private BitmapDTO() { }

    public void setBitmaps(List<Bitmap> bitmaps) {
        this.bitmaps = bitmaps;
    }

    public List<Bitmap> getBitmaps() {
        return bitmaps;
    }

}
```

Source activity:

```
BitmapDTO.getInstance().setBitmaps(myBitmaps);
Intent intent = new Intent(InputProcessingActivity.this, CompareActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

And finally, on your target activity:

```
private List<Bitmap> myBitmaps;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
    myBitmaps = BitmapDTO.getInstance().getBitmaps();
    // Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: I actually used this method before and it goes well, but the only problem is that the static variable won't last too long in meomry and if the activity is paused and resumed maybe it won't find my variable. But here is a thumbup for your work, well done :)

Comment: Then assign the values in the `onResume` callback and you won't have that problem. I'd definitely go for this method instead of storing your bitmaps in files (even though it's still a good idea and will still solve your problem) as it's a more IO-costly operation than simply keeping it temporarily in the memory.

Comment: Actually I will try your solution as well and give you feedback.

Answer (score 2):

Persist your `Bitmap`s to some files and pass the paths of file via the intent.

Comment: Can this be the fastest and fiable way to do it ?

Comment: It's pretty fast as it is. You could even persist the bitmaps in parallel.

Comment: I worked with files before, and as I remember when I load files they aren't in order, and I need my Bitmaps to be in the order I save them

Comment: Pass the file paths in the same order as the bitmaps.

Comment: I will try your method and if it's working well I will be happy to accept your answer.